# Windows 7 Backup & Restore

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup, restore

I manually deleted some backups from my hard drive but they still appear in the Windows 7 Backup & Restore Restore Files list. Does anyone know how I can remove the non-existent backup files from the list?

Answer (score 0):

First try rebooting to see if that clears the UI.  If that doesn't, remove them in The Backup and Restore Center:

> Choose Start→Control Panel. Under the System and Security heading, click the Back Up Your Computer link.
>
> The Windows 7 Backup and Restore Center appears.
>
> Click the Change Settings link.
>
> The Backup and Restore Center shows you a full analysis of the space occupied by your data backups and system image (“ghost”)
>   backups.
>
> Shadow copies/previous versions aren’t listed here because they’re stuffed into each drive’s system restore area.
>
> Click the View Backups button.
>
> The Backup and Restore Center shows you a list of all backups that have taken place recently, noting the size of the backup.
>
> If you want to delete a backup, click it once and then click Delete.
>
> Look for the really old, really big backups. Don’t worry — you’re only deleting the backup, not the original data.
>   Click Close and then click X to close the Backup and Restore Center.

http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-7/how-to-delete-old-backup-files-in-windows-7/